# Can you calculate a joint probability from the individual probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose you only know all the individual (marginal) probabilities $P(X_i)$, $P(Y_i)$. $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. Is there a way to calculate a given joint probability $P(X_j,Y_j)$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have marginal probability distributions i.e. only $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$, it is not possible to calculate joint PDF unless you have additional information like dependence structure or conditional distributions. (Assuming $X$, $Y$ are not independent).